# How to bind view data to model properties

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model with a property like this

```
public class Category { public string statename { get; set; } }
```

i got a variable from my view using ajax as shown below

```
<script language="javascript"> function getlgass() {   var staname = $('#mylist option:selected').text();//this is a htmlhelper dropdownlist. i got the selected text from this list and saved it in that variable $.ajax({ url:'/Ministry/sendProp', type:'POST', data: JSON.stringify(staname), contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', success: function (data) { alert(data.success); }, error: function(){alert("Error")} });// i'm posting it to my controller function using ajax $.getJSON('@Url.Action("getLGA","Ministry")', function (costs) { var $sel = $("#schLga"); $sel.empty(); $.each(costs, function (index, element) { $("<option/>").text(element).appendTo($sel); }); }); }   alert("something changed"); </script>
```

i need to pass that variable to the property in my model so that i can use it in the function getLGA to perform a server request
my controller function are as shown

```
  [HttpPost] public ActionResult sendProp() { // i think i'm supposed to attach the value to my model property here, but i don't know how. return Json(new { success = true }); }   [AllowCrossSiteJson] public ActionResult getLGA() { try { Category c = new Category();   getMethods.getState(c); char[] chars = { ',' };   int statepos = c.Name.IndexOf(c.statename);//i need that value here string stateindex = c.ID.ElementAt(statepos).ToString();   testStealthServ.countries csd = new testStealthServ.countries(); List<string> sth = csd.getlocal(stateindex).ToList<string>(); foreach (var v in sth) { string[] splits = v.Split(chars);   c.lgaName.Add(splits.ElementAt(0)); c.lgaID.Add(splits.ElementAt(1)); }   return Json(c.lgaName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); } catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; } }
```

Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is terminology here that is not used as expected, but here is something you might use to start with...

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult sendProp(Category pModel) {
    //If you put a breakpoint here, pModel.statename will have the value from getlgass().
    string state = pModel.statename;
    return this.Json("success");
}
```

Javascript:

```
$.post('/ministry/sendProp', { statename: getlgass() }, function (data) { alert(data); });
```

Comment: please i don't understand what you mean by populated do u mean i should do this  pModel.statename = //something ? that's the point i'm missing.

Comment: No, I mean that due to the fact that statename: was used in the post data, the MVC system will populate that value for you before the controller starts processing.  I can't tell from the question if you are interested in posting data or retrieving data back from the server to display.

Comment: i'm interested in retrieving data from a dropdown box on the view and using it in a controller function. so i thought, if i can create a property in the model to hold the value, then i can retrieve the value from the controller function getLGA() and use it there

Comment: I updated my answer.  Hopefully it will be more helpful now.  There is some magic that goes on.  You may need to try this sample code and walk through it in the debugger.